# Can I have 2 pieces of grouped information at column level rather than row?

Tags: ag-grid

Is it possible for my ag-grid pivot table to have 2 pieces of grouped information but at column level rather than row.

e.g. World would appear as a column heading rather than drill down.
https://plnkr.co/edit/X7hfRlj5IIgA1kS0q2jQ?p=preview

```js
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Country", field: "country", width: 120, rowGroup: true, enableRowGroup:true},
    {headerName: "Region", field: "region", width: 120, rowGroup: true, enableRowGroup:true, valueGetter: () => "World"},
    {headerName: "Year", field: "year", width: 90, pivot: true, enablePivot:true},
    {headerName: "Date", field: "date", width: 110},
    {headerName: "Sport", field: "sport", width: 110},
    {headerName: "Gold", field: "gold", width: 100, aggFunc: 'sum'},
    {headerName: "Silver", field: "silver", width: 100, aggFunc: 'sum'},
    {headerName: "Bronze", field: "bronze", width: 100, aggFunc: 'sum'}
];

var gridOptions = {
    autoGroupColumnDef: {
      headerName: 'Country'
    },
    pivotMode: true,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    groupDefaultExpanded: 1
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinners.json');
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var httpResult = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
            gridOptions.api.setRowData(httpResult);
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script> var __basePath = ''; </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-enterprise@21.1.0/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js"></script></head>
<body>

<div id="myGrid" style="height: 100%;" class="ag-theme-balham"></div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `groupMultiAutoColumn: true,` to your grid options and hopefully the result is what you want

```
var gridOptions = {
    defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true
    },
    groupMultiAutoColumn: true,
    autoGroupColumnDef: {
      headerName: 'Country'
    },
    // set rowData to null or undefined to show loading panel by default
    pivotMode: true,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
};
```

reference: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#configuring-auto-column